# Find rank for a given matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $v\in\mathbb{R}$ and let

$V=\begin{pmatrix}v&1&1&1\\1&v&1&1\\1&1&v&1\\1&1&1&v\end{pmatrix}$

now by using the row-echelon method, we switch row 1 for row 2

\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&v\\1&v&1&1\\1&1&v&1\\v&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}

replace row $2$ by (row $2-$row $1$), replace row $3$ by (row $3-$row $1$), and replace row $4$ by (row $4-a$ row $1$)

\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&v\\0&v-1&0&1-v\\0&0&v-1&1-v\\0&1-v&1-v&1-v^2\end{pmatrix}

replace row $4$ by (row $4 +$row $3+$row$2$)
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&v\\0&v-1&0&1-v\\0&0&v-1&1-v\\0&0&0&-v^2-2v+3\end{pmatrix}

Now, if rank $V\not=4$ then there should be at least one zero row, so we let

$-v^2-2v+3=0$

$(v+3)(v-1)=0$

$v=-3,\space v=1$

Thus, rank $V\not=4$ when $v\in\mathbb{R}$\ {1,-3}

Is my value for $v$ wrong or am I missing any values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A square matrix has full rank iff it is invertible. Thus we can approach such problem by calculating the determinant of $A$. More precisely, one has

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & a & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & a & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & a
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
a + 3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
a + 3 & a & 1 & 1\\
a + 3 & 1 & a & 1\\
a + 3 & 1 & 1 & a
\end{vmatrix}
& =
(a+3)
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & a & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & a & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & a
\end{vmatrix}\\\\
&
=
(a+3)
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & a-1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & a - 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & a - 1
\end{vmatrix} = (a+3)(a-1)^{3}
\end{align*}

Since we are interested in the cases where $\text{rank}(A)\neq 4$, it suffices to set $\det(A) = (a+3)(a-1)^{3} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You are ultimately correct here: there are indeed exactly two values of $a$ for which the rank of this matrix is less than $4$, and they are $1$ and $-3$. Your method is mostly sound, but you do leave one small hole here. When you get to
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&a\\0&a-1&0&1-a\\0&0&a-1&1-a\\0&0&0&-a^2-2a+3\end{pmatrix},$$
and conclude that there must be a $0$ row, you are implicitly assuming that the above matrix is already in row-echelon form. This is indeed the case, provided that the leading entries in the second and third rows are non-zero (i.e. $a \neq 1$). If they were $0$, then the second and third rows would be $0$, meaning that the rank of the matrix is certainly less than $4$.

Fortunately, $a = 1$ is also a root of $-a^2 - 2a + 3$, so no solutions were lost in the end. But, this is still a logical flaw in your argument. What you should do is consider separately the case where $a = 1$ and conclude that the matrix has rank less than $4$. Then, consider the case $a \neq 1$, say that the above matrix has row-echelon form, and conclude that the last row must be $0$, giving the other solution $a = -3$.

Comment: To be fair, ultimately, the matrix is in row-echelon form even when $a = 1$; it has three $0$ rows. But, I'm not convinced from your argument that you considered this!